# Clustering groups that have replicated measures: hierarchical clustering on group-average VS regression tree

Tags: clustering, k-means, cart, model-based-clustering

I measured 2 continous dependent variables (V1 and V2) on 10 occasions (10 replicates) for each of 4 groups.

I aim to cluster my groups. i.e. I dont want to cluster replicates, since this could mix groups inside a cluster. I see two options:

1. hierarchical clustering on group-average (V1mean and V2mean)
2. multiple regression tree(MRT) with replicated measures as dependent variable and
   group as independent variable

NB1: I am not interested in the hierarcical structure. Kmeans partitionning on group average would be also OK for me.

I guess the MRT solution is more usefull since it give an idea on the significance of the resulting clusters. However, I never saw multiple regression tree used like that. Could you please confirm that I am not wrong. Here is a working exemple with R.

Data simulation and visualisation:

```
gp=gl(4,10)
V1=rnorm(40,c(rep(1,10),rep(4,10),rep(8,10),rep(7,10)),rep(2,40))
V2=rnorm(40,c(rep(1,10),rep(4,10),rep(8,10),rep(7,10)),rep(2,40))
levels(gp)=paste("g",levels(gp),sep="")
df=cbind.data.frame(gp,V1,V2)
summary(df)
f.se=function(x)sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
df.m=ddply(df,.(gp),summarize,V1m=mean(V1),V1se=f.se(V1),V2m=mean(V2),V2se=f.se(V2))

ggplot(df,aes(V1,V2,color=gp))+geom_point()+
  geom_point(data=df.m,aes(V1m,V2m,color=gp),shape=4)+
  geom_errorbarh(data=df.m,aes(V1m,V2m,xmin=V1m-V1se,xmax=V1m+V1se,color=gp),shape=4)+
  geom_errorbar(data=df.m,aes(V1m,V2m,ymin=V2m-V2se,ymax=V2m+V2se,color=gp),shape=4)
```

Option 1: hierarchical clustering on group average

```
htree=hclust(dist(apply(df.m[,-1],2,scale),"euclidean"))
plot(htree)
```

Option 2: MRT

```
mrt=mvpart(data.matrix(apply(df[,-1],2,scale))~gp,data=df,xv="min")
```

We can see that MRT suggests a difference between gp 1 et 2, which is not obvious as regards the results of hierarchical clustering

Comment: Clustering is clustering, unsuperwised method; regression tree is classification, superwised method. Why to expect them to agree?

Comment: @ttnphns I don't expect similar results in term of tree, but I expect similar results in term of group appartenance to a same cluster, once tree are cutted (i.e. composition of clusters irrespectively of the hierarchy between cluster). I expect that since the only dependent variable in the MRT is the factor group and consequently terminal leaves are clusters of one or more groups (replicates are not mixed among MRT leaves). If I am not on the right track, what would you suggest for clustering (not necessarily hierachicaly) groups while keeping informations about replicates ? Thanks in advance